# Where can a service running under the "local service" account save its state

Tags: security, windows-services

I have a windows service (actually a serviced component) implemented in native C++. I want to be able to run it using the NT AUTHORITY/LOCAL SERVICE account but I want it to be able to store some startup-state information somewhere. Is there somewhere that the local service account has write access to? As far as I can tell, the built-in accounts don't get home directories like normal user accounts do.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows XP, the *LOCAL SERVICE* account does have a home directory in *Documents and Settings*.  In Vista/7, the *LocalService* account (along with other *SYSTEM* accounts) stores its data (by default) in C:\ProgramData.

You can access the folder in C# like:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

So I assume you would access it in a similar way in C++.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed to know. The actual environment variable is called "ProgramData".

Comment: ...actually, I've done some more poking around and that's not the whole story. The ProgramData directory is available on Vista/7 (not XP) but the localservice and networkservice accounts also still have their home directories. These are now located under C:\Windows. The good old UserProfile environment variable points the way on XP and Vista/7.

Comment: Also see the answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accou